# Двоит текст VK API(python)

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, api, вконтакте

Приветствую дорогие читатели. Хотел сделать упоминание всех участников беседы, всё сделал, но осталась проблема, троит текст при уведомлении.

Код:

```
def get_members():
    members = vk11.method("messages.getConversationMembers",
                      {"peer_id": 2000000003})

    members1 = json.loads(json.dumps(members))['items']
    names = json.loads(json.dumps(members))['profiles']
    members_ids = [member['member_id'] for member in members1 if 
    member['member_id'] > 0]
    members_names = [name['first_name'] for name in names]
    print(members_names)
    message = 'Вы были созваны для привлечения внимания!'

    for name in members_names:
        for member_id in members_ids:
            message += f'[id{member_id}|{name}]'

    vk11.method("messages.send",
            {"peer_id": 2000000003,
             "message": message,
             "random_id": random.randint(0, 2048)})
```

Вот что получается:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотелось бы, что бы упоминание проходило по типу: 
Данила, Сергей. (с выделением профиля при наведении на ссылку)

**Спасибо.**

Comment: Проверьте через диспетчер задач сколько у вас запущено процессов `python.exe` и/или `pythonw.exe`. И оставьте только один.

Comment: Дело в коде, а не в процессах)

Comment: Проставьте пжл отступы в коде

Comment: @n1tr0xs сделано.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте заменить этот фрагмент кода

```py
for name in members_names:
    for member_id in members_ids:
        message += f'[id{member_id}|{name}]
```

Вот этим фрагментом

```py
for i in range(len(members_names)):
    message += f'[id{members_ids[i]}|{members_names[i]}]'
```

Суть проблемы в том, что вы для каждого имени перебираете все ID
Т.е. если у вас будет 3 имени, оно будет выводить каждое 3 раза. Будет 4 имени - каждое выведет 4 раза

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй с этим кодом:

```
def get_members():
    members = vk11.method("messages.getConversationMembers",
                      {"peer_id": 2000000003})

    members1 = json.loads(json.dumps(members))['items']
    names = json.loads(json.dumps(members))['profiles']
    members_ids = [member['member_id'] for member in members1 if 
    member['member_id'] > 0]
    members_names = [name['first_name'] for name in names]
    print(members_names)
    message = 'Вы были созваны для привлечения внимания!'

    for n, name in enumerate(members_names):
        message += f'[id{members_ids[n]}|{name}], '

    vk11.method("messages.send",
            {"peer_id": 2000000003,
             "message": message,
             "random_id": random.randint(0, 2048)})
```